# null pointer in C++

Tags: c++

everyone, I have some question about C++, what do You actually prefer to use

```
int* var = 0;

if(!var)...//1)
or
if(var == 0)..//2)
```

what are the pros and cons? thanks in advance

Comment: I agree with the others on option 1. Although you should probably get used to writing `int* var = std::nullptr;`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Null_pointer_constant

Comment: Just as a side note, when comparing a variable to a constant value, place the constant on the left side, e.g. `if (0 == var);` this way you avoid bugs as if you accidentally forget one `=` the compiler will tell you.

Comment: @Trinidad: nice recommendation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always been taught to use `if (!var)`, and it seems that all the idiomatic C(++) I've ever read follows this.  This has a few nice semantics:

- There's no accidental assignment
- You're testing the existence of something (ie. if it's NULL).  Hence, you can read the statement as "If `var` does not exist" or "If var is not set"
- Maps closely to what you'd idiomatically write if `var` was a boolean (bools aren't available in C, but people still mimic their use)
- Similar to the previous point, it maps closely to predicate function calls, ie. `if (!isEmpty(nodeptr)) { .. }`

Answer (score 9):

I prefer `if (!var)`, because then you cannot accidentally assign to `var`, and you do not have to pick between `0` and `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly personal preference.  Some will advise that the first is preferred because it becomes impossible to accidentally assign instead of compare.  But by that same token, if you make a habit of putting the rvalue on the left of the comparison, the compiler will catch you when you blow it:

```
if( 0 == var )
```

...which is certainly true.  I simply find `if( !var )` to be a little more expressive, and less typing.

They will both evaluate the same, so there's no runtime difference.  The most important thing is that you pick one and *stick with it*.  Don't mix one with the other.

Answer (score 1):

Either one is good, though I personally prefer 2 - or something like it.

Makes more sense to me to read:

```
if ( ptr != NULL )
```

than

```
if ( ptr )
```

The second I may confuse for just being a boolean to look at, but the first I'd be able to tell immediately that it's a pointer.

Either way, I think it's important to pick one and stick with that for consistency, though - rather than having it done in different ways throughout your product.

Answer (score 1):

*A few years has passed...*

The C++11 standard introduced `nullptr` to check for null pointers and it should be used as it ensure that the comparison is actually done on a pointer.
So the **most robust check** would be to do:

```
if(myPtr != nullptr)
```

---

The problem with `!var` is that it's valid if var is a boolean or a numerical values (int, byte etc...) it will test if they are equal 0 or not.
While if you use `nullptr`, you are sure that you are checking a pointer not any other type:

For example:

```
int valA = 0;
int *ptrA = &valA;

if(!valA) // No compile error
if(!*ptrA) // No compile error
if(!ptrA) // No compile error

if(valA != nullptr) // Compile error, valA is not a pointer
if(*ptrA != nullptr) // Compile error, *ptrA is not a pointer
if(ptrA != nullptr) // No compile error
```

So, it's pretty easy to make a mistake when manipulating pointer to an int as in your example, that's why `nullptr` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer option 3:

```
if(not var)
{
}
```

The new (well since 1998) operator keywords for C++ can make code easier to read sometimes.

Strangely enough, they seem to be very unknown. There seem to be more people who know what trigraphs are (thank you IOCCC!), than people who know what operator keywords are. Operator keywords have a similar reason to exist: they allow to program in C++ even if the keyboard does not provide all ANSII characters. But in contradiction to trigraphs, operator keywords make code more readable instead of obfuscating it.

Comment: What do you mean "new" keyword operators? `not` has been in the C++ standard from day one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the High Integrity C++ coding Standard Manual: *for comparison between constants and variables you should put the constant on the left side to prevent an assignment instead of an equality comparison*, for example:

```
Avoid:
if(var == 10) {...}

Prefer
if(10 == var) {...}
```

Particularly in your case I prefer if(0 == var) because it is clear that you are comparing the pointer to be null (0). Because the ! operator can be overloaded then it could have other meanings depending on what your pointer is pointing to:  **if( !(*var) ) {...}**.

Comment: @ybungalobill: What do you mean?

Comment: According with the C++ MSDN reference:
Logical Negation Operator !:
For an expression e, the unary expression !e is equivalent to the expression (e == 0), except where overloaded operators are involved.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k6w8551(VS.80).aspx

Comment: It's a reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307 , don't take it seriously.

Comment: However, still the overloading argument makes no sense. You can overload neither !x nor x == 0 for built-in type of x. But if x is not built-in then !x is more likely to be meaningful than x == 0.

Comment: @ybungalobill: int result = 0; if(1 == StandardsAreApplied ) { int result = MistakesArePrevented; } else { result = ProblemsCouldHappen; }

Answer (score 0):

1. DON'T use NULL, use 0.
2. Strictly speaking, pointer is not bool, so use '==' and '!=' operators.
3. NEVER use 'if ( ptr == 0 )', use 'if ( 0 == ptr )' instead.
4. DON'T use C-pointers, use smart_ptr instead. :-)

Comment: out of curiosity: why shouldn't one use NULL? Again, it makes it more clear that your dealing with a pointer in the check than say, checking an int value isn't zero (which is quite common when guarding against divide-by-zero).

Comment: Matthew Wilson and Bjarne Stroustrup recommend using 0 instead NULL, because NULL - it's a macros defined in different ways on different platforms, but 0 - always zero. And strictly speaking, NULL is a part of C language, not C++.